# Constructor that implements something

Tags: c#, constructor

I have the code below and I'm trying to understand what it does:

```
readonly Ido _do;

public Main(): this(new doX()) { }

public Main(Ido do) {
    _do = do;
}
```

What does this do in the first constructor?

```
this(new doX())
```

and why the application firstly start by

```
Main(Ido do)
```

and then call the

```
this(new doX())
```

while I believe it should be other way round

Comment: The default constructor calls the overloaded one with a default value, being new doX().

Comment: It has nothing to do with implementation. Don't mess up ":" here

Comment: Try rephrasing the question in readable English!

Comment: I tried to rephrase the second part of the question , hope it is readable enough

Comment: this(new doX) won't compile - surely it's this(new doX()) - i.e. invoking a constructor for the doX class? Are you sure the code compiles and you've actually copied it accurately into the question?

Comment: Still its not clear, what do you mean by `application firstly start by`

Comment: The question keeps changing so it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @Servy well when I run the application and put the debugger on both constructors, it first hit the second constructor and then hit the main constructor

Comment: That's because the syntax: public Main(): this(new doX()) { } literally means call a constructor taking a parameter, then execute the body of this constructor.

Comment: @CraigShearer yes, the code is compilable at my end, the bit that you are pointing was not in the code and it was in the comment, so don't be picky ;)

Comment: If you're asking for help, it pays to be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking the default constructor - i.e. with no parameters - by calling `new Main()` will firstly execute the `this(new doX())` which invokes the second constructor.

Try stepping through the code in the debugger and it should become clear.

Answer (score 0):

`this(new dox)` is calling the constructor that is parameterized Constructor for your class. You can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the **this** keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Call the other constructor of the class.

```
: base(...) // Call a base class contructor
: this(...) // Call another constructor in the same class
```